# String (literal array) to Array conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string, type-conversion

I have a string of the form:

```
string '["a"=>[10,20,30,40=>"Forty"],"b"=>[100,200,300,400=>"Four Hundred"],"c"=>[15]]' (length=78)
```

I need to convert this directly into an array as

```
array (size=3)
  'a' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => int 10
      1 => int 20
      2 => int 30
      40 => string 'Forty' (length=5)
  'b' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => int 100
      1 => int 200
      2 => int 300
      400 => string 'Four Hundred' (length=12)
  'c' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => int 15
```

I have tried parse_str and json_encpde/decode and eval, but none of them see the variable as anything other than a string. Please help!

Comment: where did you get this anyway?

Comment: I am trying this approach. The string is actually retrieved as-is from a database, and I am wondering if this format would make it easier to process.

Comment: Can't test it right now but can you try eval-ing the thing?

Another idea would be to write the string to `php://memory` and then do `include 'php://memory'`

Comment: Don't bother. Arrays aren't meant to be stored as literal strings in this way. Store it with `json_encode` or `serialize` then retrieve it with `json_decode` or `unserialize`

Comment: I know. :) Like I said, it was just an approach I wanted to try out.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to just `eval` the thing

```
$string = '["a"=>[10,20,30,40=>"Forty"],"b"=>[100,200,300,400=>"Four Hundred"],"c"=>[15]]';
$array = eval("return $string");
print_r($array);
```

Keep in mind though that both of these solutions actually evaluate PHP code that you didn't write yourself. If you can, I'd suggest storing this data as JSON or using `serialize_array()` instead

**Could not make this example to work, leaving it for archive purposes or for somebody else to give a try**

Can't test it right now but one of these might be able to help you IF you run a PHP version that supports the [] array notation.

```
$string = '["a"=>[10,20,30,40=>"Forty"],"b"=>[100,200,300,400=>"Four Hundred"],"c"=>[15]]';
file_put_contents('php://memory', $string);
$array = include 'php://memory';
print_r($array);
```

Comment: can you explain the code detailed, i can not able to understand this.i read the concept of eval function, its just convert the string into PHP code, after converting that , there is no result is display.

Comment: `eval` will simply *evaluate* aka run the given string. By design eval does not return a value, unless a `return` is executed in it. That's why in the second line of my example I add the `return` before the string variable

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this hope will help this.    
$input_string =  '["a"=>[10,20,30=>"test",40=>"Forty"],"b"=>[100,200,300,400=>"Four Hundred"],"c"=>[15]]'."<br/>";
    $s1 = str_replace('],','-',str_replace(']]','',str_replace('[','',$input_string)));
    $s2 = explode("-",$s1);
    foreach ($s2 as $key => $value) {
        $s3[] = explode("=>",str_replace('=>"','-"',$value));
        $s4[$s3[$key][0]] = $s3[$key][1];

    }
    foreach($s4 as  $keys => $v) {
        $value = explode(",",$v);
        foreach($value as $val) {
            if(strrchr($val,'-'))
            {
                $final[$keys][array_shift(explode("-",$val))] = end(explode("-",$val));
            }
            else
                $final[$keys][] = $val;
        }
    }
```